# SQL searching dates for a certain condiition

Tags: date, search, sql-server-2012

I have a table of stock closing prices.

```
Ticker  Date    Close
BCD 06/28/18     7.45 
BCD 06/27/18     8.01 
BCD 06/26/18     7.51 
BCD 06/25/18     8.24 
BCD 06/24/18     8.09 
BCD 06/23/18     8.41 
BCD 06/22/18     8.66 
BCD 06/21/18     10.42 
BCD 06/20/18     10.42 
BCD 06/19/18     10.73 
BCD 06/18/18     10.72 
BCD 06/17/18     10.44 
BCD 06/16/18     8.74 
BCD 06/15/18     8.70 
BCD 06/14/18     8.49 
BCD 06/13/18     6.00 
BCD 06/12/18     5.87 
BCD 06/11/18     5.97 
BCD 06/10/18     5.91 
BCD 06/09/18     5.89 
BCD 06/08/18     6.40
```

I want to find the last date when the close was <= today's price.

Latest price is 7.45, so it would be 6/13/18.

What's the best way to code this in SQL 2012?

Comment: Something like `SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM prices WHERE Close <= (SELECT Close FROM prices WHERE Date = GETDATE()) AND Date < GETDATE() ORDER BY Date DESC`?

Comment: Greg, my output shows a date header but no date.  The Select Top 1 Statement generates 6/28/18, but the where clauses are not working

Comment: I added in Where Ticker = 'BCD' and still get blank date for output

Comment: What does the subclause `SELECT Close FROM prices WHERE Date = GETDATE()` give you?

Comment: px_close header  with no value.  Could it be with GETDATE(), which is the system date (6/29/18), whereas the max data in table is 6/28/18?

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. You said "today's price"... Does it work to just replace `GETDATE()` with `(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM prices)` in both places?

Comment: error msg: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FRO XML is also specified.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. SQL Server 2008, so maybe there's some incompatibility with 2012, but it seems straight-forward.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM prices
  WHERE [Close] <= (
    SELECT [Close] FROM prices WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM prices)
  )
  AND [Date] < (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM prices)
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```